# Fast drawing lots of lines in Android Canvas: dealing with antialiasing and KitKat's peculiarities

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas

I need to draw lots (~10k/frame is a common quantity) of lines fast. Known ways to draw those lines (single-threaded, antialiased):

- `drawLines()` with a hardware accelerated `Canvas`. Fast, but the lines get antialiasing blur (see the picture below). Also, on `KitKat` nothing is drawn if the points array contains `NaN` values
- `drawLines()` with a software rendered `Canvas`. Moderate speed, no blur, `KitKat` problem remains
- `for (int i ...) drawLine()` with a hardware accelerated `Canvas`. The slowest of the three listed, no blur, no `KitKat` problems

Something tells me there is a couple of simple tricks to avoid both antialiasing and `KitKat` issues keeping the performance high

For the first one - is it possible, for example, to draw those lines not antialiased and then apply antialiasing to the whole bitmap (a variation of the fastest option)?

For the second - no ideas but some trimmer method dealing with `NaN`s. Anyway, `KitKat` is a relatively new and popular - there should be some solutions for its issues - otherwise the platform would be quite a headache to use

**UPD2:**
This question contains *two separate issues:*
- Antialiasing when using `drawLines()` with hardware acceleration and arbitrary (yet valid) input
- `drawLines()` refusing to draw anything on `KitKat` if the input contains `NaN`s

`drawLines()` is in focus because it is *way* faster than, for example, drawing the lines one by one using `drawLine()`

Also, the pictures below are the results of applying `drawLines()` two times to the same array:

```
canvas.drawLines(toDraw, 0, qty, paint);
canvas.drawLines(toDraw, 2, qty-4, paint); //qty % 4 == 0
```

**UPD**:
That's how the blur looks like. It's on the ends of the lines

[image: Pic1]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by antialiasing "blur" ? Anti-aliasing is, by definition, a sort of a blur.  Maybe a picture to describe the problem?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: So, I'm guessing those NaNs are causing the problems on the GPU side. Just as a sanity check, have you done a software pass to remove the NaNs before drawing (just to see if that's the visual issue?)

Comment: I did not, but there were different sets of points: containing `NaN`s and not. The latter are drawn on `KitKat`. And I doubt it's on the GPU side - the `NaN` problem is `KitKat`-specific and is not affected by the rendering mode

Comment: Double sanity test : where are the NaNs? are they at the end of each line segment? (which is where it looks like the visual issue is occurring in the picture?). Dont' forget that Android will go through and tesselate all those line segments into a set of GPU primitives. NaNs make GPUs do weird things. It wouldn't surprise me if you're seeing a byproduct of that.

Comment: They are paired so if a point has a `NaN` coordinate, the other one will also be `NaN`. I did it to avoid lines drawn towards random directions on the other platform versions. By the way, the problem with antialiasing and the problem with `NaN`s are absolutely separate and not connected to each other. The picture illustrates the blur, not `NaN` issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87525/discussion-between-colt-mcanlis-and-alex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is just the result of what was written in chat (see Colt's post):

1) The original input array is split into pieces containing no NaNs
2) Those pieces are split so that maximum difference between line lengths in sub-pieces is less than `4x` (experimentally obtained value). Applying `drawLines()` to the final sub-arrays results in no blur and rather good performance

Answer (score 3):

There's a tangle of topics here; Let's try to unravel them.

**Line "blurring"**

Based on our chat, this issue only shows up once you start drawing line segments whose length < 1px. It's worth noting that `drawLines()` will tesselate all the line segments at one time, and likely the tessellator is falling over due to the presence of <1px lines in the set. This is the reason you're not seeing the "blurring" with using individual `drawLine()` commands; each `drawLine()` tessellates only the segment you've given it, so the errors are bound to just those super small segments (that are too small to see anyhow). **The fix here** is to add in some logic to remove the <1px length lines from your set, and this will fix the issue, and allow you to use `drawLines()` which is faster than the other methods.

**NaNs issue**

NaNs cause lots of problems on GPUs, so it makes sense that if they are included in your drawing list, that you would see problems. (much like the <1px line segments that are causing the blurring issues). Again, this is why you don't see visual problems using individual `drawLine()` commands; NaNs are breaking the tesselator, and isolating it only to those single segments, rather than the entire line list. Again **the solution here** would point to filtering the list to remove NaNs.

**Performance**

Given than the overhead of tessellating a line is significantly larger than a CPU check to discard a bad line, it would make sense that adding a pre process to remove the NaNs and <1px lines should be within your performance budget, and would remove the visual issues you're seeing.